# How searching files on the client-side from a webservice placed on the server?

Tags: c#, web-services, client-server

I have a webservice. The webservice is calling from the Server side. 
And when the service looking to the c-drive, he's looking in the Server area. When you expected that the c-drive is on the client-side.

```
 if (!File.Exists(filename)) // filename = "C:\\temp\MyFile.pdf"; must by on the client-side. But it looks on the server-side.
     throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("File not found: '{0}'!", filename));
```

I want to see "C:\temp\MyFile.pdf" on the client-side and "\\MyServer\c$\temp\MyFile.pdf" on the server-side.

What do I have to do?

Comment: so what about the code you pasted?

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: So what? work on that approach and do the implementation. this is the way how you can check the file availability.

Comment: If the file has a value "C:\temp\MyFile.pdf". then the system has looking on the client-side and not on the server-side. What do I have more to explain. The system looks on the server-side and not on the client-side. I must change something in the code. This is not exactly the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code,

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\MyServer\share\MyFile.pdf");
bool exists = fi.Exists;
```

***Note: You have to transform your file path to above format.***

Updated with the conversion part,

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"c:\share\MyFile.pdf");
string clientPath= @"\\MyServer\share\";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(clientPath,fileName));
bool exists = fi.Exists;
```

Comment: How can you convert @"\\c:\\temp\\MyFile.pdf".Replace("\\", "\");?

Comment: Now I have to do @"\\MyClient\temp\MyFile.pdf" and @"c:\share\MyFile.pdf"

Comment: I can something with this solution. Help! Only I don't have hardly time.

Answer (score 0):

can't do.

you can try redesign your app/system, that the webservice/server will expecting the pdf to be uploaded as well.

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean? The webserver can you calling from the Internet Explorer.